# can't get server response from dropzone.js parallel upload

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to get the server response from a set of uploads using dropzone.js parallel uploading so that I can maintain the uploader's intended file order as I register the files in a mySQL database.  My files are being uploaded just fine, and the "successmultiple" event is being fired as expected - but server response is empty.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var filedrop = new Dropzone("#filedrop", {
        parallelUploads: 2,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        init: function() {
            this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        },
        url: "upload2.php"
    });
});
```

If I assume the response is json and attempt to parse it as such:

```
               var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                $(json).each(function(i,val){
                        $.each(val,function(k,v){
                                console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
                        });
                });
```

I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` error.  Is the response empty because I haven't echo'd anything from my upload2.php file?  I'd like to get a response that gives me information about file order while retaining the important ability to do parallel uploads. Am I completely barking up the wrong tree trying to determine the file order with server response? Are there any dropzone.js experts in the wings?

Comment: _"It the response empty because I haven't echo'd anything from my upload2.php file?"_ This appears to be case?

Comment: I would assume your last statement is correct as there is no response coming through. Depending on how your data is formatted in the PHP side of things, you may also have to make use of the JSON decode/encode functions.

Comment: I was able to get at the order of files with `accepted=filedrop.getAcceptedFiles()` ...I guess I'm just wondering how I can match up the uploaded files with the expected order.  Guess I can echo the temp file names and `$_FILES['file']['name']` back as a response from the upload form and match them up with the `accepted` array.